# How to use pandas dataframes from user input

Tags: python, oop, pandas, boolean

Using python 3 coding and 
pandas version 0.18.1

I am trying to make my program more dynamic by giving user options to filter data from dataframe.

My questions are:

1) How do I make my user choices available for filtering in dataframe?

2) Is there a better way to do this?  Mabye with function or classes?

Assume my df is the following:

```
df.dtypes

PIID    object    
fy      object
zone    object
```

If fy is grouped:

```
df.groupby('fy').PIID.count()

fy
2014    38542
2015    33629
2016    32789
```

If zone is grouped:

```
df.groupby('zone').PIID.count()

AZW - Acquisition Zone West        3909
NAZ - Northern Acquisition Zone    1167
SAZ - Southern Acquisition Zone    2983
```

Normally I can just create a new dataframe with filters by doing the following:

```
year = df['fy'] == '2016'    
zone = df['zone'] == 'AZW - Acquisition Zone West'

newdf = df[year & zone]
```

But how can I make this more dynamic by providing user options?

At this point I provide the user some options with booleans for fy:

```
print ('What is the interested year?')
print ('1. 2014')
print ('2. 2015')
print ('3. 2016')

year = input('> ')

if year == '1':
    year1 = df['fy'] == '2014'
elif year == '2':
    year2 = df['fy'] == '2015'
```

And some booleans for zone:

```
print ('What is the interested zone?')
print ('1. AZW - Acquisition Zone West')
print ('2. NAZ - Northern Acquisition Zone')
print ('3. SAZ - Southern Acquisition Zone')


zone = input('> ')

if zone == '1':
    zone1 = df['zones'] == 'AZW - Acquisition Zone West'
elif zone == '2':
    zone2 = df['zones'] == 'Northern Acquisition Zone'
```

At this point I don't know how to receive the user choices

```
newdf = df[choice1 & choice2]
```

where choice 1 is the year and choice 2 is the zone.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my stab at it. You will need to create your own error messages and handlers for incorrect input though.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"PIID":[38542,33629,32789], 
                   "fy":["2014","2015","2016"], 
                   "zone":["AZW - Acquisition Zone West", "NAZ - Northern Acquisition Zone", "SAZ - Southern Acquisition Zone"]})


def get_choice(data, column):
    """
    Gets user choice
    """
    nums = [val for val in range(len(df[column].unique()))]
    choices = list(zip(nums, df[column].unique()))
    print("What '%s' would you like?\n" % column)
    for v in choices:
        print("%s.  %s" % (v))
    user_input = input("Answer: ")
    user_answer = [val[1] for val in choices if val[0]==int(user_input)][0]
    print("'%s' = %s\n" % (column, user_answer)) # Just tells the user what they answered
    return user_answer

def main():

    year_input = get_choice(data=df, column="fy")
    zone_input = get_choice(data=df, column="zone")
    newdf = df.loc[(df["fy"]==year_input)&(df["zone"]==zone_input)]
    print(newdf)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So if you input something like "0" for the first option (year) and "0" for the second option (zone) your output should be something like:

```
    PIID    fy                         zone
0  38542  2014  AZW - Acquisition Zone West
```

It *should* scale, but like I said, you will obviously have to add your own custom tweaks. This should be enough for you to generalize off of, and solves the problem posed in your question. After reading the code you have I'd just recommend you implement the DRY principle in your work (Do Not Repeat Yourself (e.g., using a ton of if statements)). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, ralston!  You nailed it.  Totally good enough to generalize off.